# Android : Convert CharSequence to Int in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-application

I'm confused on how can I convert `CharSequence` to int , I just want to set visibility of textfield when the inputted amount of `edt_nma_amount` `is >=100`

> What I tried to convert it

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
```

> but it returns me an error  It crashes my app because the number is like string ""

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

**java**

```
 public void nmaAmount(){
    edt_nma_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

            if (number >=100){
                tilNmaReason.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                tilNmaAmount.setError(null);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Updated**

I have this data

```
  String amt = edt_nma_amount.getText().toString();
  int numbers=Integer.valueOf(amt);
```

**but it returns me an error** AT `int numbers=Integer.valueOf(amt);`
I think it is `NumberFormatException`

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? "" is no number is the message. An empty string is no number.

Comment: @blackapps It crashes my app because the number is like string `""` in the first run

Comment: Check if the input is empty string, if that's the case, return

Comment: Your app does not have to crash if you catch that exception.

Comment: @blackapps I tried using catch but it will stop eventually
I put an updated situation above can you see what's the problem? need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the code inside onTextChanged call back

```
              if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString())) {
                     Long number =    Long.parseLong(s.toString());

                if (number >= 100) {
                    tilNmaReason.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    tilNmaAmount.setError(null);
                }

            }else{
                tilNmaAmount.setError(null);
            }
```

Comment: I have updated code above, and I have a question is there anything wrong with this line ? `int numbers=Integer.parseInt(edt_nma_amount.getText().toString());` I have an error of image above : NumberFormatException

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza Please check the updated answer. Integer will support only unto 32 bit that's the reason it's getting exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if onTextChanged gives you an empty string or not before calling parseInt.

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if (s.toString().isEmpty()) { // <----
            tilNmaAmount.setError(null);
        } else { // <----
            int number = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

            if (number >=100){
                tilNmaReason.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                tilNmaAmount.setError(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I put an updated situation above can you see what's the problem? need help

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza it's because that value is bigger than the MAX_VALUE of Integer, which is 2147483647.
A quick way to fix it is using Long.parseLong(), but to be safe you should use try catch too, or restrict the length of user input via edit text.